# VS Code: history in Python Interactive Window

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When typing commands into the field at the bottom (where it says "Type 'python' code here and press Enter to run), these commands are added to some sort of history. Using Cursor-Up and Cursor-Down I can go back and forth through the commands I typed in a session. When re-executing commands from the history so retrieved, these commands are not appended to the history again. So for example I browse the command history with 5x Cursor-Up, find `command` I'm looking for, execute it, type one other line, and now have to press Cursor-Up 6 times to execute `command` again. Can this be changed?